# Code not reachting the lines in code which it should

Tags: c#, winforms

For some reason, my code doesn't seem to reach the last few lines.
I've added the stop point and the return point in the code.
I don't see anything wrong with the data source I use on that row whenever I check it out in debug.
The code seems to set the value there and jumps back to the top of the foreach loop.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
                //We check if the user has already filled in some info
return point   if (row.Cells[7].Value != null && row.Cells[6].Value != null && !askedTheUser)
                {
                    //trigger for message if you want to replace them
                    Message m = new Message("There is already info present in the category and or size dropdown. Would you like to overwrite this?", "Overwrite", "YESNO");

                    if (m.Awnser) {
                        overwrite = true;
                    }
                    askedTheUser = true;
                }

                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cat = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[6];
                string toMatch = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                //Now we will start matching
                //First we try to match with the package ( if that is filled in )
                if (row.Cells[5].Value != null && (string)row.Cells[5].Value != "") {
                    toMatch = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                    matchWithPackage = true;
                }

                Regex re = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");
                Match result = re.Match(toMatch);

                string alphaPart = result.Groups[1].Value;
                string numberPart = result.Groups[2].Value;

                Datagridview dgv = new Datagridview();

                if (numberPart.Length < 4) {
                    numberPart = numberPart.PadLeft(4, '0');
                }
#if DEBUG
                Console.WriteLine(numberPart);
#endif
                //Matching the category
                if (CHIP != null && CHIP.Contains(alphaPart))
                {
                    cat.Value = "CHIP";
                }
                else if (SOJ != null && SOJ.Contains(alphaPart))
                {
                    cat.Value = "SOJ";
                }
                else if (PLCC != null && PLCC.Contains(alphaPart))
                {
                    cat.Value = "PLCC";
                }
                else if (QFP != null && QFP.Contains(alphaPart))
                {
                    cat.Value = "QFP";
                }
                else if (SOP != null && SOP.Contains(alphaPart))
                {
                    cat.Value = "SOP";
                }
                else {
                    if (cat.Value != "") {
                        cat.Value = "";
                    }

                    cat.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                    cat.Style.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                    continue;
                }

                //Setting the matched color
                cat.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                cat.Style.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen;

                //Adding the dropdownlist to the size cb
                (row.Cells[7] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DataSource = dgv.AddSeconderyCombobox(dataGridView1, row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());

                if (!matchWithPackage) {
                    continue;
                }

                //Matching the size
 Stop Point     List<string> sizeList = (List<string>)(row.Cells[7] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DataSource;
  Doesn't reach this and beyond               List<string> matchedList = sizeList.FindAll(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(numberPart));

                if (matchedList.Count > 0) {
                    (row.Cells[7] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DataSource = matchedList;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You have a continue just above the if.  So you are always getting !matchWithPackage

Comment: I'm guessing one of the `continue`s is being hit. Which, and why, is best worked out by stepping through the code in the debugger and seeing which conditions are hit.

Comment: One of those cases for which debugging line-by line was invented.

Comment: It is failing :if( row.Cells[5].Value != null && (string)row.Cells[5].Value != "")

Comment: Sorry i should have added this in the question ,and i will edit. The continue statement is never reached the matchWithPackage is always true ( this is build in for a later expension ). And wouldn't the next statment never been reached if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i fixt my own problem and i'm going to awnser my own question i case somebody comes across a similar problem.

```
if (sizeList != null) {
                    List<string> matchedList = sizeList.FindAll(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(numberPart));
                    if (matchedList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        (row.Cells[7] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DataSource = matchedList;
                    }
                }
```

After adding the few last lines in an extra check that needed to be done I noticed that the code was being executed, but the matchedlist.count was always 0.

So what was happening is that the code after that was redundant as the matchList was 0 and the debugger just skipped jumping to these lines ( a bit confusing if you ask me ).